# Jquery .dialog not opening from image input in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 tabs, each has a table. Last column of each table has an input type=image to open a model dialog form. Javascript hides the form fine but the dialog doesn't open when I click the input image in any of the rows. I want to be able to add a comment to any of the rows. Works on a simple form but not how I'm using it in a table. Any clues? Thanks.

Tabs

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="activeTab"><a href="#tab1">En route</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Arrived</a></li>
</ul>
```

Each tab has a table

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>Add Comment</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="enrouteShipments">
    <tr id="7453">
        <td>Company A</td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="images/icons/dark/pencil.png" id="addComment"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="7454">
        <td>Company B</td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="images/icons/dark/pencil.png" id="addComment"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Dialog Form (hidden)

```
<div id="dialogAddCommentForm" title="Enroute Comment">
    <form class="mainForm" id="addCommentForm" method="post" >
        <label>Comments:</label>
        <textarea rows="8" cols="" name="textarea" id= "addAComment"></textarea>
        <div class="submitForm"><input type="submit" value="Add Comment" class="blueBtn" id="addCommentBtn"/></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#dialogAddCommentForm" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, width: 500 });
        $( "#addComment" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialogAddCommentForm" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID of an element must be unique, use class attribute to group similar elements, when you use id selector it will fetch only the first element with the given id

```
<input type="image" src="images/icons/dark/pencil.png" class="addComment">
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#dialogAddCommentForm" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, width: 500 });
        $( ".addComment" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialogAddCommentForm" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hLQVF/)